# Why was the question on benchmarking apps for concurrent key value stores closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

I liked [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/198057/25936), asking how to make a benchmarking app or give information on already usable code to test map implementations.

Sure it needed a code reference but why close it?

Comment: @kjell add a language ref to your question and defend it here or tell if you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

First, let me explain the closure. Questions that essentially ask for a list of external resources (apps, books, whatever) are the archetypal "not constructive" ones, and some could also be closed as "not a real question" (the overly broad ones). Usually this type of question ends up being a list of everyone's favourite resource, and that's not *really* helpful to anyone. We are looking for solutions to problems, not for (just) what people like.

I also suspect that your (deleted) answer helped push the question towards getting closed. It reads more like a comment than an answer, some good information in there, but not really a solution to the problem. When a question generates comment-like discussion-y answers, it's an extra hint that it should be closed. In the future, if you don't feel you can directly and fully answer the question, please use comments instead.

(all) That said, I've re-opened the question. I feel the topic (benchmarking concurrent key-value stores) is specific enough for the question to *not* degenerate into a list of everyone's favourite application. I may be completely wrong about this, but having had (more or less) the same need a year ago, I feel confident in saying that this is not a question that can be answered with a simple Google search. In all likelihood the application the asker looks for doesn't exist (yet), when I searched for it the only solution was to build your own.

Of course, if I'm wrong and the question takes a "not constructive" turn, we'll just close it again.

Comment: I had a similar read on that question when I reviewed it for closure.  Right on the edge, and it needed some work, more views and answers to determine where it was going to head.  I think your decision to re-open was the right one.  But that's a given with the diamond.  ;-)